# Getting return value from stored procedure in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BK_NUMBER]
    (@Category NUMERIC(38, 0)) 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
   DECLARE @RunningNumber Int
   DECLARE @min Int
   DECLARE @max Int
   DECLARE @newRunningNumber Int

   BEGIN

      SELECT @RunningNumber = RunningNumber
      FROM PARKMARKENNUMMER
      WHERE PARKMARKENTYP_ID = @Category

      UPDATE PARKMARKENNUMMER 
      SET RUNNINGNUMBER = @RunningNumber + 1
      WHERE PARKMARKENTYP_ID = @Category 

      SELECT @newRunningNumber = RunningNumber
      FROM PARKMARKENNUMMER 
      WHERE PARKMARKENTYP_ID = @Category 

      RETURN @newRunningNumber;
End;
```

I try to get `@newRunningNumber` with this VB code:

```
 Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(MSSQL_Helper.strConnectionBookit)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("BK_NUMBER", sqlConnection)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID
        Dim returnParameter As SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int)
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        sqlConnection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlConnection.Close()
        Dim returnValue As Integer = returnParameter.Value
        Return returnValue
```

But it returns always "0". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you execute your SP in SQL server for the category you are passing as parameter and verified that it is not returning 0?

Comment: Use an OUTPUT parameter, not a return value. Return value is for error/status codes, not for data!

Comment: When you look in DB does RunningNumber in PARKMARKENNUMMER have a value? If null, the add would give null and perpetuate.

Comment: Before someone else gets to it, I've edited your title to remove the `in Vb.net` - you generally [shouldn't put tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) unless they need to be there for the title to make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not actually returning the value:

```
RETURN @newRunningNumber
```

However, as **Aaron Bertrand** said, you should either set it as an `OUTPUT` parameter or `SELECT` it back out.

OUTPUT:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BK_NUMBER]
(
    @Category NUMERIC(38, 0),
    @newRunningNumber INT
)

Dim newRunningNumber As SqlParameter("@newRunningNumber", SqlDbType.Int)
newRunningNumber.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
// execute
Dim returnValue As Integer = newRunningNumber.Value
```

SELECT:

```
SELECT @newRunningNumber AS NewRunningNumber

Dim returnValue As Integer = CType(command.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the other posts, OUTPUT parameter is the way to go, most people dont realize that you can put more than a single line into your command text.  Because you can, you can convert something a DBA did into something you can use, without changing your stored procedure. For example:

```
CMD.CommandText = "DECLARE @return_value int;EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[BK_NUMBER] (@Category = " & ID & ";SELECT @return_value"
Dim Ret as int32 = CMD.ExecuteScalar
```

This is just an example of what you can do.  You should of coarse use parameters to avoid injection and have proper error handling, etc etc...